# Spitting out objects from array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, object, nsmutablearray

I'm quite new to classes and objects and I have a question:

- I'm keeping track of books which can be input by textFields.
- 3 properties per book: Title, Author and Description.

What I'm trying to do is get all the objects of books in a `NSMutableArray` called: Collection. 
(at the moment it's only 1 book (`objectAtIndex:0`)
Which is currently working but when I try to spit them back out I only get the description of the book. I'd love to get all the items (title, author, description).

What I've been wondering is: should I make a new (collection) class for example called BookCollection and make an array there? But how would I init it etc?

The code is below, help and tips are welcome!
(Started about a month ago)

`Book.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Book : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString* title;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString* author;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString* description;

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)newTitle withAuthor:(NSString*)newAuthor andDescription:(NSString*)newDesription;
```

`Book.m`

```
#import "Book.h"

@implementation Book
@synthesize title,author,description;

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)newTitle withAuthor:(NSString*)newAuthor andDescription:(NSString*)newDesription{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        title = newTitle;
        author = newAuthor;
        description = newDesription;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

`AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize lblTitle,lblAuthor,lblDescription;
@synthesize collection;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    //alloc the array that will hold the books
    collection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //create a new book
    Book *newBook = [[Book alloc]initWithTitle:[lblTitle stringValue] withAuthor:[lblAuthor stringValue] andDescription:[lblDescription stringValue]];

    //logging the items of the book
    NSLog(@"%@",newBook.description);
    NSLog(@"%@",newBook.title);
    NSLog(@"%@",newBook.author);

    //adding the book to the collection
    [collection addObject:newBook];


    //logging the book items from the collection

    NSLog(@"%@",[collection objectAtIndex:0]);

    //problem... only logs 1 item from the object...

}
@end
```

`AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Book.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *collection;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *lblTitle;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *lblAuthor;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *lblDescription;
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: its pretty simple @Ben Vertonghen Just remove `collection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` line from Your Click method it will be done. Initialize your array in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method. make this change and you are done.

Comment: You should not use "description" as a property name, as, at the very least, there will be confusion with the standard `description` method defined in NSObject and overridden in many methods.  You want `description` to work the "normal" way, and dump a representation of your object.

Comment: Good to keep in mind, @HotLicks! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your Book class's `-description` method.

When you call `NSLog(@"%@", someObject)`, the object's `-description` method gets called and placed inside the `%@` format specifier. You'll want to override your Book class's `-description` method to print out all of the object's fields.

Have a look [here](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/01/overriding-nsobjects-description/) for a good example.

To clarify, when you call:

```
NSLog(@"%@",newBook.description);
NSLog(@"%@",newBook.title);
NSLog(@"%@",newBook.author);
```

You are (quite correctly) logging each individual field. However, when you call:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[collection objectAtIndex:0]);
```

You are essentially writing:

```
NSLog(@"%@",newBook); // Gets an NSString from [newBook description];
```

And so you need to implement `- (NSString *)desctiprion` for the `Book` class to get the logging behaviour you are after.

Answer (score 0):

`Step 1` : remove `collection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` from `- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender` and put it into `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method. Problem is You are initializing your array each time you add New Book to Collection Array.

`To Iterate` : all the objects of Array use following snippet

```
[collection enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
    Book *objBook = (Book *)obj;

    NSLog(@"%@",objBook.description);
    NSLog(@"%@",objBook.title);
    NSLog(@"%@",objBook.author);;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

This Description Method is amazing! I had no idea it was even possible @PLPiper! Thank you

Although it gets harder... at this very moment I'm just logging it all out (for me as a developer). But for example... if I wanted all these properties in labels (string value). So if I wanted to spit them all out through my array, how would that work?

I've seen code that uses the following example(sort of) which I like and it's an easy-read.

```
for (int i = 0; (i<=[collection.count]); i++) {
    [titleLabel setStringValue:[dateCollection objectAtIndex:i].title]
    [authorLabel setStringValue:[dateCollection objectAtIndex:i].author]
    [descriptionLabel setStringValue:[dateCollection objectAtIndex:i].description]

}
```

In theory this should work, but in practice I'm missing something here...

Comment: Rename the `description` property to something else and then write a new `description` method that returns a formatted string containing all your fields.

Comment: A lazy way to do the description method: `return @{@"title"=self.title, @"author"=self.author, @"Description"=self.Description}.description;`.  (I think I got that syntax right.)